# What is the best option in my case?

Tags: android, time

So I want to display a dialog on the screen when a SMS is received and remove it from the screen after 5 seconds but also have the ability to click on it and cancel the timer to keep it on the screen. So I learned I have a few options here. I could use a Handler, Timer or AlarmManager (any others?) What would be the best in my case? Can you give an example on how to use whichever the best option is?

Comment: just question: do you mean your application screen, or the phone screen even if your application is running in the background. something like facebook chat bubble

Comment: Phone screen. Yes my popup will be like FB chat bubble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- since you need something like bubble view in facebook chat
  here is a simple example how to do it, but you need to customize your solution:

**start by createing layout for your view like:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Exit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stay_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Stay" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**now create serive to build your view:**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BubbleViewService extends Service
{
    private WindowManager       windowManager                   = null;
    private View                rootView                        = null;
    private Intent              intent                          = null;
    private int                 timeToExit                      = 5000;
    private boolean             autoExitFlag                    = true;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    this.intent = intent;
    Log.v("BubbleViewService", "onStartCommand");
    iniView();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v("BubbleViewService", "onCreate");
}

private void iniView()
{
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    rootView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_dialog, null);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity  = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    TextView tvMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Msg");
        tvMessage.setText(message);
    }

    windowManager.addView(rootView, params);

    startExitHanlder();

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.exit_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            BubbleViewService.this.stopSelf();
        }
    });

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.stay_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            autoExitFlag = false;
        }
    });

    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = params.x;
                initialY = params.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.x = initialX + (int)(event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                params.y = initialY + (int)(event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(rootView, params);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if(rootView!=null) windowManager.removeView(rootView);
}

private void startExitHanlder()
{
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(autoExitFlag==true) BubbleViewService.this.stopSelf();

        }
    }, timeToExit);

}
```

}

**you need to add this service to your manifest xml file:**

```
<service
    android:name="your.pkg.path.BubbleViewService"
    android:label="My Service" >
```

**and finally from your application activity start this service as needed using the following code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BubbleViewService.class);
            intent.putExtra("Msg", "Blah blah blah ... what ever");
            MainActivity.this.startService(intent);
```

as I said you can customize your service as your application requirements, in this example I added handler to stop the service after 5 seconds if the auto exit flag is true.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution is very interesting, but while the dialog is on-top, it's not possible to click on any icons or elements on the background. How this could be achieved?